# Rest resource error in WSO2 dataservice with procedure with out param

Tags: rest, wso2

Hi I am creating a WSO2 data service and i am calling a stored procedure that has an out param.

```
{call ? :=IRIS_REST_PKG.INSERT_OR_UPDATE_STUDENT(?,?,?) }
```

So i can get the whole thing to work in the try it editor but when i configure the rest resource i see a list of request params which includes my out param that was earlier defined in the query. 
When i call the rest service with only in params i get:

```
Value type miss match, Expected value type - 'null', but found - 'STRING'.
```

I am using version  6.4.0 of Enterprise Intergrator.
This is my dbs file:

```
<data name="IRIS" transports="http https local">
   <config enableOData="false" id="ORACLE">
      <property name="driverClassName">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
      <property name="url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap:...</property>
      <property name="username">xxxxxxxxxxxx</property>
      <property name="password">xxxxxxxxxxxx</property>
      <property name="dataSourceProps"/>
      <property name="dynamicUserAuthMapping">
         <configuration/>
      </property>
   </config>
   <query id="get_student" useConfig="ORACLE">
      <sql>{call ?:=TEST_PKG.get_student(?)}</sql>
      <result element="upi" rowName="">
         <element column="upi" name="upi" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="research_summary" name="research_summary" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param name="result" sqlType="ORACLE_REF_CURSOR" type="OUT"/>
      <param name="upi" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
   <query id="q1" useConfig="ORACLE">
      <sql>{call ?:=TEST_PKG.myfunction(?,?)}</sql>
      <result element="myCount" rowName="">
         <element column="myCount" name="myCount" xsdType="integer"/>
      </result>
      <param name="myCount" sqlType="INTEGER" type="OUT"/>
      <param name="ename" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="eid" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
   </query>
   <query id="insert_or_update_student" useConfig="ORACLE">
      <sql>{call ? :=IRIS_REST_PKG.INSERT_OR_UPDATE_STUDENT(?,?,?) }</sql>
      <result outputType="json">{"result":{"status":"$status"}}</result>  
      <param defaultValue="-1" name="status" sqlType="INTEGER" type="OUT"/>
      <param name="upi" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="summary" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="optIn" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
   </query>
   <query id="get_jstudent" useConfig="ORACLE">
      <sql>SELECT UPI, RESEARCH_SUMMARY FROM xxx r WHERE r.UPI = :upi</sql>
      <result outputType="json">{"result":{"upi":"$upi","research_summary":"$research_summary"}}</result>
      <param name="upi" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
   <operation name="get_student">
      <call-query href="get_student">
         <with-param name="upi" query-param="upi"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
   <operation name="op1">
      <call-query href="q1">
         <with-param name="ename" query-param="ename"/>
         <with-param name="eid" query-param="eid"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
   <operation name="insert_or_update_student">
      <call-query href="insert_or_update_student">
         <with-param name="upi" query-param="upi"/>
         <with-param name="summary" query-param="summary"/>
         <with-param name="optIn" query-param="optIn"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
   <operation name="get_jstudent">
      <call-query href="get_jstudent">
         <with-param name="upi" query-param="upi"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
   <resource method="GET" path="r1">
      <call-query href="get_student">
         <with-param name="result" query-param="result"/>
         <with-param name="upi" query-param="upi"/>
      </call-query>
   </resource>
   <resource method="POST" path="insertOrUpdateStudent">
      <call-query href="insert_or_update_student">
         <with-param name="status" query-param="status"/>
         <with-param name="upi" query-param="upi"/>
         <with-param name="summary" query-param="summary"/>
         <with-param name="optIn" query-param="optIn"/>
      </call-query>
   </resource>
   <resource method="GET" path="get_jstudent/{upi}">
      <call-query href="get_jstudent">
         <with-param name="upi" query-param="upi"/>
      </call-query>
   </resource>
</data>
```

I am talking about: insertOrUpdateStudent resource section.

```
<with-param name="status" query-param="status"/>
```

I have also removed this line but still not working.
I also tried and pass null / 0 / "" and still not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that if the resource and the operation have the same name things go wrong. Also even with the above correct the wizard shows the out param as a query param, so the thing to do is to edit the xml and remove the out param from the resource parameters.